# Sequelize many-to-many relationship: How to get result based on AND condition?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I was hoping someone would help me out with this or provide an alternative if I'm mistaken.
I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

Let's say for simplicity sake there is the `Events` , `Users`, `EventUsers` where `EventUsers` table has `eventId`,`userId`.

How can I achieve all the events from the `Events` table based on the condition where users should be explicitly `abc@test.com` and `cde@test.com`.

I tried doing something like this but to no avail.

```
await Event.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: User,
        attributes: ['email'],
        through: {
          model: EventUsers,
          attributes: [],
        },
        where: {
          [Op.and]: [{ email: 'abc@test.com' }, { email: 'cde@test.com' }],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

```
Event table
------------
id | title
------------
1  | lorem
2  | ipsum


User table
------------
id | email
------------
1  | abc@test.com
2  | cde@test.com
3  | efg@test.com


EventUsers table
------------
eventId| userId
------------
1  | 1
1  | 2
2  | 1
2  | 2
2  | 3
```

This must give me event with id 1 where emails are both `abc@test.com` and `cde@test.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try "Op.or" instead of "Op.and" in where condition.

Comment: Tried that out however that would return all instances where even a single email would exist and not both. I should then filter the output which I do not want to do.